# graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear strange result (XNA)

Tags: xna, c#

I have such Execution:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Color(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

Alpha is 0. So why it draws me Red color?

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(new Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
```

Also draws the same red color. Changing alpha value doesn't affects the color on the screen. Why?

Comment: I've reverted your edit - if you have a new question please create a new question :)

Answer (score 3):

The alpha value in the backbuffer does not affect what is scanned out to the screen.

However it does affect blending. For example, non-premultiplied alpha blending is:

```
output = source * sourceAlpha + destination * (1-sourceAlpha)
```

While the above uses the **source** alpha only (giving you the "transparency" effect you expect), you can also set up the blending stage to use the **destination** alpha. Most sane blend modes only use the source alpha - but using the destination alpha lets you do some fun special effects ([example](http://andrewrussell.net/2013/02/optimising-dark/)).

In XNA you can change the blend function by creating an instance of `BlendState` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433713.aspx)).

The other reason to have an alpha value for the destination buffer is if it is a render target. When you go to use that render target as a texture,  the alpha values stored in its buffer will behave as you would expect for a texture.